# Selected ListItem value using SelectableContainerEnhance in Material-UI

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I'm really new to [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and trying to work with [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) components on a new [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) app I'm working with. A classic use case has come to my needs: a list of items changes the UI when the user selects or not some ListItem. Surprisingly, I found that React isn't easy with parent-child component relations like that.

I tried to follow the [Material-UI Docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list), implementing *SelectableList* component like the docs suggests using the [SelectableContainerEnhance class](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/hoc/selectable-enhance.js). Then I went this way:

```
const {ListItem, Avatar, Divider} = mui;

App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      players: Players.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 } }).fetch()
    }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <SelectableList subheader="Players list">
        {this.data.players.map((player) => {
          return (
            React.Children.toArray([
              <Divider />,

              <ListItem
                value={player._id}
                primaryText={player.name}
                secondaryText={player.score}
                leftAvatar={<Avatar>{player.name}</Avatar>} />
            ])
          );
        })}
      </SelectableList>

      <Divider />

      { true /* What to do now? */ ?
       (<span>Thanks!</span>) :
       (<span>Click a player to select</span>)}
    );
  }
});
```

Ok, the list items has become selectable. *But how to know if any ListItem is selected? And how to get the value and adjust the UI according to it?*

Answer (score 0):

They talk about setting up a `valueLink` in the documentation.

```
<SelectableList
  subheader="Players List"
  valueLink={{
    value: this.state.selectedIndex,
    requestChange: this.handleUpdateSelectedIndex
  }}>
```

And then define a `handleUpdateSelectedIndex` to set the state:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {selectedIndex: 1};
},
handleUpdateSelectedIndex(e, index) {
  this.setState({
    selectedIndex: index,
  });
},
```

This will give you `this.state.selectedIndex` on your App component that you can do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I implemented exactly this way like the [Material UI List documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list) suggests. The problem is *how to know if anything is selected* outside the component (i.e. inside the App class, where my code showns the comment `/* What to do now? */`). I'm really new to React, maybe it's very easy, but I can't understand the best approach to follow.